# 2 way data binding with jade form

Tags: angularjs, pug

I'm trying to attach two text input fields to the $scope using ngModel. Here is my code:

```
extends layout

block content
    h1 hello from partials
    form(name='login') 
        label(for='username') username
            input(type='text' name='username' id='username' ng-model='credentials.username')
    br
    label(for='password') password
        input(type='text' name='password' id='password' ng-model='credentials.password')
    button(type='submit') submit
```

Even after I press submit the credentials do not change on the $scope. They are set to empty string by default, and stay that way after submitting. Is my jade form not written correctly?

The controller code looks like this:

```
myApp.controller('mainController' , function($scope){
    window.scope = $scope;
    $scope.credentials = {username: '' , password: ''}
})
```

and layout.jade looks like this:

```
doctype html
html(ng-app='myApp')
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
  body
    div(ng-controller='mainController')
    block content
    script(src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js')
    script(src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular-route.js')
    script(src='/javascripts/myApp.js')
```

Comment: There is not enough code here to determine what the problem is. Where is the relevant `ng-controller` in the view for the scope holding the model? And where in the view are you outputting the values?

Comment: ng-controller is inside layout.jade. I'm just testing Angular for the first time so I'm not sure if I should be trying to assign an ng-controller for each view. The values are not being output anywhere. I'm just trying to see them attached the $scope object.

Comment: Ah turns out ng-controller needs to be assigned to a div in each of the views. That totally did the trick, $scope is now being updated.

Answer (score 1):

Your `block content` is not nested under your controller, which is why `ng-model` is not changing your scope.

This would work :

```
div(ng-controller="mainController")
  block content
```

But you'll probably want a per-page controller anyway (you can still keep this one, though - controllers act like a hierarchy, in the same way as JS prototypes)